React call function after form submitted
APP.js
import "./App.css";
import * as call_server from './To_server.js';
import Form from './Form';

function App() {
  console.log(call_server.Ldap_connect('bob', 'zzzz')) // work fine!

  const onChangeName = (formData) => {
    console.log(formData.username)  // return 'bob'
    console.log(formData.pass)      // return 'zzzz'
    console.log(call_server.Ldap_connect(formData.username, formData.pass)) // ** bug when submit! **
  };  

  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <Form onSubmit={onChangeName}/>
    </div>     
  );
}

export default App

Form.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Form({ onSubmit }) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        pass: '',
    });

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        onSubmit(formData); // Pass the form data to the parent component
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={formData.username}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="pass"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={formData.pass}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
             
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Form;

To_server.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


// *** get LDAP connect ***  
export function Ldap_connect(username, pass){
   const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  
   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchPost = async () => {
         const response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:8000/ldap_connect?id=${username}&pass=${pass}`
         );
         const data = await response.json();         
         setData(data);
      };
      fetchPost();
   }, []);
   
   return (data)
}

In React, I'm trying to get the "username" and "pass" values from form ​​to send a command to the server with these values.
console.log(call_server.Ldap_connect('bob', 'zzzz')) // work fine!
console.log(call_server.Ldap_connect(formData.username, formData.pass)) // bugs when submit
ERROR
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Ldap_connect is indeed a custom hook, but you're calling it as a normal function to return a result.  If that's the intended use, remove its internal state management and just have it return that result.
For example:
export async function Ldap_connect(username, pass){
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:8000/ldap_connect?id=${username}&pass=${pass}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

Then you'd just need to resolve the returned Promise:
const onChangeName = (formData) => {
  console.log(formData.username);
  console.log(formData.pass);
  call_server.Ldap_connect(formData.username, formData.pass).then(console.log);
};


Alternatively, if you want it to be a hook then the structure and usage would need to work like a hook.  The hook itself can maintain state and update that state when you call a function.
For example:
export function useLdap() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const Ldap_connect = async (username, pass) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8000/ldap_connect?id=${username}&pass=${pass}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();         
    setData(data);
  }

  return { data, Ldap_connect };
}

The hook now exposes the state value and a function.  You'd invoke the hook in the main body of the component, and call the function wherever you like:
import { useLdap } from './To_server.js'; // Note: The file should be re-named for consistency

function App() {
  const { data, Ldap_connect } = useLdap();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  const onChangeName = (formData) => {
    console.log(formData.username);
    console.log(formData.pass);
    Ldap_connect(formData.username, formData.pass);
  };

  // the rest of the App component...
}

It's a fairly significant change in how the functionality is used.  Hooks generally are more like React components than like simple functions that return a result.  The hook returns the elements that you can use, in this case the state value and a function to update the state value.  The component would respond to the updated state from the hook as it would any other updated state.

First example work fine !   Thank you David
